# wordpress multisite and buddypress username allow uppercase

Tags: wordpress, buddypress, multisite

I am using wordpress multisite and buddypress the usernames are restricted to use only lowercase when a uppercase is used in the username then I get the error message,

> Usernames can only contain lowercase letters (a-z) and numbers.

Like to know is there any working plugin or code change I could do to allow usernames to have capital letters.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by adding this to your functions.php :

```
remove_filter( 'sanitize_user', 'strtolower' );
```

More info in the codex : http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/sanitize_user

Comment: I have added it to my functions.php but still the uppercase is not accepted in the username. Do you have any suggestion in it.

Comment: Hi @RafH - Also interested to know how to do this.